# Weird problem with href attribute of anchors in Rails 3.1.0.rc4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, hyperlink, anchor

In my Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application, if I do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Back to Feature Index", features_path %>
```

I get this in the view :

> Back to Feature Index (/features)

SO, I tried this:

```
  <a href = "blah"> HTML link </a>
```

and I got this:

> HTML link (blah)

I don't know why is this happening.

**UPDATE:**
In the first case, the HTML generated is:

```
<a href="/features">Back to Feature Index</a>
```

and the same is with the second case.

SO, I guess its something to do with the CSS. How can I fix this?

Comment: could you please elaborate more

Comment: There is nothing else to elaborate, I was runnig my application normally and suddenly this started.
If I add any anchor, the href gets automatically printed out in brackets and I didn't do anything that could result in such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two examples you gave, what are the values of 1) the linked text, and 2) the `href` in the generated HTML?

If the `hrefs` are correct, but the linked text is not, it's possible that a stylesheet is adding the (href) displayed portion.

Try adding `a:after { content: ""; }` to your stylesheet.

Comment: thanks, I got it. It was a stylesheet issue and I was scratching my head looking in other places.